# Standard error of the mean in a repeated measures study

Tags: repeated-measures, standard-deviation

I am having difficulty figuring out how to calculate the SEM and report it in a table.  I have 5 different time periods, and for those time periods 6 different measures of digestibility for each animal:

```
horse   period   adfdig'y   ndfdig'y
1         1         45.1      70.2            
2         1         48.2      69.8         
3         1         55.6      59.0      
4         1         49.1      57.0
5         1         42.0      66.3          
6         1         46.0      60.2
1         2         56.3      70.6
2         2           etc, etc,
```

So the issue I'm having is building an ANOVA table like this with the SEM:

```
item, unit            treatment (time period)
              p1   p2  p3   p4    p5   SEM
ADF, %                      
NDF, %
```

How do I get one SEM for ADF digestibility over the time periods?

Comment: What do you mean by "ANOVA table"? The example you show isn't what I would normally call an ANOVA table.